# Dynamic ACL in OpenLDAP

Tags: dynamic, permissions, set, openldap, expand

I've some problems with realising some permission granting to an OpenLDAP instance via regular expressions for quite some hours now – probably there is someone out there who can help ;)

I want the members of a group to administer a tree structure, the group is member of it. I've tried some acl settings – I'll post my trials below the basic structure.

(Sorry for THAT long question )

---

### Basic structure

The structure is somehow like that tree – behind an `#` symbol, there is a brief description what the entries are meant for.

```
dc=example,dc=com
│
├── cn=admin                  # OpenLDAP default admin user 
│
├── ou=entities               # organisational entities
│   │
│   ├── o=e1                  # first of these entities
│   │   │
│   │   ├── cn=admin          # groupOfNames – see bullet points below
│   │   │   ┆
│   │   │   └ ┄▸ member: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
│   │   │   └ ┄▸ member: uid=j.doe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
│   │   │
│   │   ├── cn=role1          # groupOfNames to be reused below
│   │   │   ┆                   as recursive group members within
│   │   │   ┆                   permission groups
│   │   │   ┆
│   │   │   └ ┄▸ member: cn=admin,o=e1,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com
│   │   │
│   │   └── cn=role2
│   │       ┆
│   │       └ ┄▸ member: cn=admin,o=e1,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com
│   │
│   └── o=e2
│       ├── cn=admin
│       ├── cn=role1
│       └── cn=role2
│
├── ou=groups                 # permission groups for applications
│   │                           that authenticate against OpenLDAP
│   │
│   ├── cn=globaladmins       # groupOfNames – superusers in all applications
│   │   ┆
│   │   └ ┄▸ member: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
│   │
│   ├── cn=ldapadmins         # groupOfNames – same rights as admin user
│   │   ┆
│   │   └ ┄▸ member: cn=globaladmins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
│   │   └ ┄▸ member: uid=l.dap,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
│   │
│   ├── cn=permissiongroup1   # groupOfNames – authentication group
│   │   ┆                       for specific application
│   │   ┆
│   │   └ ┄▸ member: cn=globaladmins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
│   │   └ ┄▸ member: cn=role1,o=e1,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com
│   │   └ ┄▸ member: cn=role1,o=e2,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com
│   │
│   └── cn=permissiongroup2
│       ┆
│       └ ┄▸ member: cn=globaladmins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
│       └ ┄▸ member: cn=role2,o=e1,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com
│       └ ┄▸ member: cn=role2,o=e2,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com
│
└── ou=people                 # finally the "real people" accounts
    │
    ├── uid=j.doe
    ├── uid=l.dap
    └── uid=m.muster
```

- `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com` is basic member of the `admin` groups (since every group needs at least one member).
- `uid=l.dap,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com` is member of the `cn=ldapadmins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com` group. Therefor every member should have same rights within LDAP structure as `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com`
- `ou=people` is the only structure, (personal) accounts are maintained
- `ou=groups` is the only structure, authentication groups for (web)applications are maintained (with nested members)

.

- The `cn=admin,o=e1,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com` DN members should be able to admin everything below `o=e1,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com`.
- `e1` should be *dynamic*.
- The entity admins should not be able to administer other entities than the ones, they are admins from.

---

### Permission LDIF

I've tried some different things ... and none Regex was successful :(

Since I'll post some fragments, I put every LDIF fragment within such a bash fragment:

```sh
touch /permissions.ldif

cat >/permissions.ldif <<EOF
# first of all delete all permissions
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
-


########
## LDIF blocks from below
########


-
# add general permissions
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to *
           by self write
           by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
           by set="[cn=ldapadmins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com]/member* & user" write
           by users read
           by * none
EOF

ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /permissions.ldif
```

---

#### trial 1

```
# add administrative access to LVe admin subgroups
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to dn.regex="([^,]+,)?o=([^,]+),ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com"
           by self write
           by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
           by set="[cn=ldapadmins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com]/member* & user" write
           by set.expand="[cn=admin,o=$2,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com]/member* & user" write
           by set="this/member* & user" read
           by * none
```

The result is, that `admin` and any member of `ldapadmins` can edit, the members of specific entity `admin` subgroups cannot edit.

The specific `admin` subgroups cannot even see the `entities` subtree.

---

#### trial 2

```
# add administrative access to LVe admin subgroups
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to dn.regex="o=([^,]+),ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com"
           by self write
           by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
           by set="[cn=ldapadmins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com]/member* & user" write
           by set.expand="[cn=admin,o=$1,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com]/member* & user" write
           by set="this/member* & user" read
           by * none
```

The same result as with trial 1 ...

---

#### trial 3

Additional groups – as a tree:

```
dc=example,dc=com
┆
└── ou=entity_admins
    │
    ├── cn=e1
    │   ┆
    │   └ ┄▸ member: cn=admin,o=e1,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com
    │
    └── cn=e2
```

And the LDIF:

```
# add administrative access to LVe admin subgroups
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to dn.regex="o=([^,]+),ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com"
           by self write
           by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write
           by set="[cn=ldapadmins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com]/member* & user" write
           by set.expand="[cn=$1,ou=entity_admins,dc=example,dc=com]/member* & user" write
           by set="this/member* & user" read
           by * none
```

The result is again: `admin` and any member of `ldapadmins` can edit, `entity_admins` subgroups user cannot edit – even not their "owned" entities.

---

#### trial 4

If I put an `by set="[cn=admin,o=e1,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com]/member* & user" write` for *EVERY* single `olcAccess: to dn.regex="([^,]+,)?o=jpbay,ou=entities,dc=example,dc=com"` (with all the other stuff from trial 1), everything works fine.

BUT: that's not maintainable or dynamic. So that's no solution, I can accept.

---

I do not know why `set.expand` doesn't work as expected (as explained within different online examples on openldap.com) – and was not able to find a proper documentation that could explain why. Or if there has to be some enablement of an OpenLDAP module?

If you could support me with that problem – probably with a solution – it would be great =)

Thanks a lot,
Martin

Comment: Hello Martin, did you succeed? If yes, could you share it? I'm trying to make something similar. Thank you

Comment: Hi @bipe15,

yes, I've solved my problem – it was simple and kinda stupid ...

If you have a look up to `Permission LDIF`, in my code block, I've missed to quote the `EOF` ... by using this, everything worked fine:

`cat >/permissions.ldif <<'EOF'\n
...\nEOF`

Since Stackoverflow doesn't want to let me type linebreaks or multi line comments, please read the `\n` as linebreaks etc. =D

Cheers,
Martin